# Mapper function Keys

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

For weather data examples, Hadoop definitive guide book says

"The keys are the line offsets within the file".

How are map function's keys determined? Are they always the line offsets within the input file? What if the input consist of multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

The default input format in hadoop is TextInputFormat. Which is explained [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html). In this format the files are split into lines and the key is exactly the position in the file from which the line was taken.

In order to understand how the keys and values are assigned, you need to read about input formats, which are described in a whole chapter later in the book.

Best of luck.

Comment: I just started off on the book, I shall read that. Thank you.